# How can I use fileReader to read text file data in Android Studios?

Tags: java, android, text, filereader

I have a fileReader that works in Java but the same method doesn't work for Android Studios. The code I use in Eclipse to read my text file data is:

```
public void addTextFilesToCardsArrayList(String fileName) throws IOException{
        FileReader freader =  new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(freader);
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {        //Read a file line by line
                 String[] split = line.split(",");              //Parse the line in to usable fragments
                 int cardNumber = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                 String cardId = split[1];
                 int apc = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
                 int hp = Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
                 String type = split[4];

                 Card card = new Card(cardNumber, cardId, apc, hp, type);
                 cards.add(card);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I placed a text file called "cards.txt" in the asset folder that I created in "main" directory. Normally I pass it in as a paramter like "cards.txt" in Eclipse. How do I get it working in Android Studios fileReader?

I've seen  InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt"); being used but I've liked to keep my method mostly the same without rewriting my fileReader code.

Comment: `I've seen InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt"); being used `. Indeed. That is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

> I placed a text file called "cards.txt" in the asset folder that I created in "main" directory

That is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on your Android device.

> I've seen InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt"); being used

That is the correct approach to use.

> but I've liked to keep my method mostly the same without rewriting my fileReader code.

Then pass in an `InputStream` rather than a `String` to `addTextFilesToCardsArrayList()`. Replace `FileReader` with `InputStreamReader`. In Android, use the `InputStream` from `getAssets().open()`. Elsewhere, use a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Do you mean like this:public void addTextFilesToCardsArrayList() throws IOException{
        InputStream is2 = getAssets().open("Cards4.txt");
        InputStreamReader freader =  new InputStreamReader(is2);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(freader);

Comment: @Qwisatz: Off the cuff, that looks fine.